# SwipeRefreshLayout giving exception on setting background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to set background color to the circle image view of swiperefreshlayout

It always gives an exception :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobile.clubgecko.beta/com.mobile.clubgecko.activities.ClubGeckoBaseActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffd6c00
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
```

I have used following but no luck

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fd6c00"));

swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.geckocolor));
```

Comment: Post your onCreate method from ClubGeckoBaseActivity

Answer (score 3):

I looked up the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.java#SwipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor%28int%29) on GrepCode

```
453    public void More ...setProgressBackgroundColor(int colorRes) {
454        mCircleView.setBackgroundColor(colorRes);
455        mProgress.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(colorRes));
456    }
```

They use `getResources().getColor()` to retrieve the color. If you provide a real color, not a resource id, the look up fails (as per exception). You have to provide a resource id of the color. Change from

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.geckocolor));
```

to

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(R.color.geckocolor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor()`, `setProgressBackgroundColor()` is deprecated.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressBackgroundColor(int)

The old deprecated method is expecting a resource id, but you're passing a color value.

Comment: There is no method named setProgressBackgroundColorSchemeColor in the api

Comment: According to the documentation there is.

Comment: doesn't takes in code. gives compilation error. the above solution worked for me